# How to debug epub?

Tags: epub

I've written an ePub generator by using ZipArchive in .NET and looking at the spec (in Wikipedia) & a example.

It doesn't work!  But I only get a generic error so I'm unable to fix anything from here.

Where could I go to upload my ePub and be told what is wrong with it?  Or is there a tool that is better for it?  I'm currently using Adobe ePub reader...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an online validator tool at http://www.epubconversion.com/ePub-validator-iBook.jsp.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question, but in case others come across this I wanted to contribute. The IDPF which is responsible for the ePub standard has a tool for checking ePubs called epubcheck. It can be found at https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck.

In addition, they have their own online validator that uses epubcheck. It is located at http://validator.idpf.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic black box approaches.

First: Generate a file and put it into a validator.

Second: Take a set of in- and output without using your code (other generator, example, do it manual). Then use a file comparison tool (maybe extract zip first).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good offline checking tool for Windows, Mac or Linux OS:

http://www.pagina-online.de/produkte/epub-checker/

It's a great tool which even i used to validate and generate epub files also clearly give errors if any.